# How can I get a only part of a hash in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash

Is there a way to get a sub-hash? Do I need to use a hash slice?

For example:

```
%hash = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 );
```

I want only

```
%hash = ( a => 1, b => 2 );
```

Comment: As there is nothing logically to "slice" on I suspect something to do with 'map'.
In an array you'd do it based on an index, but in a hash there is no reliably internal representation of the data in it.   You'd need some type of qualifier (regex?) to define what should go into the subhash and what shouldn't.

Comment: BTW, you hash syntax is wrong: use round braces "()" for a plain hash, "{}" for anonymous hash references.

Comment: Since this was asked so long ago, the highly voted answers miss the key-value slice  introduced in v5.20. https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/07/perl-5-20-introduces-keyvalue-slices/ (and upvote [Kjetil S.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28073653/2766176) answer)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[Hash slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) return the values associated with a list of keys.  To get a hash slice you change the sigil to @ and provide a list of keys (in this case `"a"` and `"b"`):

```
my @items = @hash{"a", "b"};
```

Often you can use a quote word operator to produce the list:

```
my @items = @hash{qw/a b/};
```

You can also assign to a hash slice, so if you want a new hash that contains a subset of another hash you can say

```
my %new_hash;
@new_hash{qw/a b/} = @hash{qw/a b/};
```

Many people will use a [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) instead of hash slices:

```
my %new_hash = map { $_ => $hash{$_} } qw/a b/;
```

Starting with Perl 5.20.0, you can get the keys and the values in one step if you use the % sigil instead of the @ sigil:

```
use v5.20;
my %new_hash = %hash{qw/a b/};
```

Comment: this makes why "map" works w/ hashes a little clearer to me. Thanks

Comment: Larry Wall, brian d foy, and...Chas. Owens...thank you for this very comprehensive explanation!

Comment: You should probably make it more clear that a hash slice just has the values, not key/value pairs.

Comment: Is there some compact syntax for slices of hash refs, or is the somewhat clunky @foo = @{$hash_ref}{qw/a b/} as good as it gets?

Answer (score 9):

You'd probably want to assemble a list of keys you want:

```
my @keys = qw(a b);
```

And then use a loop to make the hash:

```
my %hash_slice;
for(@keys) {
  $hash_slice{$_} = %hash{$_};
}
```

Or:

```
my %hash_slice = map { $_ => $hash{$_} } @keys;
```

(My preference is the second one, but whichever one you like is best.)

Answer (score 6):

Yet another way:

```
my @keys = qw(a b);
my %hash = (a => 1, b => 2, c => 3);
my %hash_copy;
@hash_copy{@keys} = @hash{@keys};
```

Answer (score 3):

Too much functional programming leads me to think of `zip` first.

With [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/dist/List-MoreUtils/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm) installed,

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(zip);

%hash = qw(a 1 b 2 c 3);
@keys = qw(a b);
@values = @hash{@keys};
%hash = zip @keys, @values;
```

Unfortunately, the prototype of List::MoreUtils's `zip` inhibits

```
zip @keys, @hash{@keys};
```

If you really want to avoid the intermediate variable, you could

```
zip @keys, @{[@hash{@keys}]};
```

Or just write your own `zip` without the problematic prototype.  (This doesn't need List::MoreUtils at all.)

```
sub zip {
    my $max = -1;
    $max < $#$_ and $max = $#$_ for @_;
    map { my $ix = $_; map $_->[$ix], @_; } 0..$max;
}

%hash = zip \@keys, [@hash{@keys}];
```

---

If you're going to be mutating in-place,

```
%hash = qw(a 1 b 2 c 3);
%keep = map +($_ => 1), qw(a b);
$keep{$a} or delete $hash{$a} while ($a, $b) = each %hash;
```

avoids the extra copying that the `map` and `zip` solutions incur.  (Yes, mutating the hash while you're iterating over it is safe... as long as the mutation is only deleting the most recently iterated pair.)

Comment: Explain this, please -- `%keep = map +($_ => 1), qw(a b);` ?

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I use Moose::Autobox here:

```
my $hash = { a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4 };
$hash->hslice([qw/a b/]) # { a => 1, b => 2 };
```

In real life, I use this to extract "username" and "password" from a form submission, and pass that to Catalyst's `$c->authenticate` (which expects, in my case, a hashref containing the username and password, but nothing else).

Comment: How is $hash->hslice(qw/a b/) better than @{$hash}{qw/a b/}?  Or is this one of those cases where if I have to ask I am too far gone to understand?

Comment: You should have an answer template so that "I use Moose::" is at the start of every answer. :)

Comment: Chas. Owens: that's not what hslice does.  @{$hash}{...} returns a list of values; hslice returns a new hash reference with both keys and values.

Answer (score 3):

New in perl 5.20 is hash slices returning keys as well as values by using % like on the last line here:

```
my %population = ('Norway',5000000,'Sweden',9600000,'Denmark',5500000);
my @slice_values = @population{'Norway','Sweden'}; # all perls can do this
my %slice_hash   = %population{'Norway','Sweden'}; # perl >= 5.20 can do this!
```

Answer (score -4):

A hash is an unordered container, but the term slice only really makes sense in terms of an ordered container.  Maybe look into using an array.  Otherwise, you may just have to remove all of the elements that you don't want to produce your 'sub-hash'.

Comment: In Perl, hash slices are useful and fully supported. To find out more re-read 
[the 'Slices' section in _perldata_](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices).