# Array access to python dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, slice

Is there a good way to Slice a dictionary?

```
N0=5000
N1=10000
N2=10000000
X = np.random.randint(N0,N1, N2) #lost of numbers between N0 and N1

remap = {x:2*x for x in X} 
t = time.time()
X_ = [remap[x] for x in X]
print('dict ', time.time()-t)
assert np.all(X_==2*X)
```

Second option using numpy slicing. However requires allocating X.max() elements

```
remap = np.arange(N1)*2
t = time.time()
X_ = remap[X]
print('numpy ', time.time()-t)
assert np.all(X_==2*X)
```

results:

dict  5.615

numpy 0.285

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at this: [Slicing a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216889/slicing-a-dictionary)

Comment: You are using a dictionary in the idiomatic way. Dictionaries do not support slicing.

Comment: First off, it's great that you've included a minimal example.  What is the problem you're trying to work around exactly?  The second option works well, and the number of elements isn't really a limitation as long as `X.max() = N1` is much less than `len(X) = N2`, which you've set it to be here.   I don't really see a problem with the first way either- that's the clearest way to get a list of items from a dict.

Comment: In the duplicate question, not all of the answers deal with your issue.  That OP needed to slice on values, not keys.  However, I see two solutions of the five that will solve your problem.

Comment: I see the solutions, and I also posted a "solution". My concern is the runtime when using list/dict comprehension.