# How to remove random excess keys and values from dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary variable with several thousands of items. For the purpose of writing code and debugging, I want to temporarily reduce its size to more easily work with it (i.e. check contents by printing). I don't really care which items get removed for this purpose. I tried to keep only 10 first keys with this code:

```
i = 0
for x in dict1:
    if i >= 10:
        dict1.pop(x)
    i += 1
```

but I get the error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: This seems to be roughly what you want to accomplish: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47704499/13526701

Comment: NoBlockhit's recommendation is probably best. If you want to "*temporarily"* reduce the size, removing elements means you might have to add them back in later to maintain the correct behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just rewrite the dictionary selecting a slice from its items.

```
dict(list(dict1.items())[:10])
```

Answer (score 1):

Select some random keys to delete first, then iterate over that list and remove them.

```
import random
keys = random.sample(list(dict1.keys()), k=10)
for k in keys:
    dict1.pop(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the dictionary into a list of items, split, and convert back to a dictionary like this:

```
splitPosition = 10    
subDict = dict(list(dict1.items())[:splitPosition])
```