# How can I store one element of a two dimensional in another hash?

Tags: perl, hashmap, perl-hash

I have a two dimensional hash.

```
myHash = (
    'a' => {
        'a1' => v1
        'a2' => v2
    }
    'b' => {
        'b1' => v3
        'b2' => v4
    }
);
```

I want to retrieve a hash like this:

```
%hashSlice = %Hash{'a'};
```

Where hashSlice should be:

```
%hashSlice = (
    'a1' => v1
    'a2' => v2
);
```

I have tried all combinations of %, $ and @ with this. I have also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979237/how-can-i-get-a-only-part-of-a-hash-in-perl).

I can't seem to get one hash out of a two dimensional hash. I don't want to use any libraries for this.
I am new to perl. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your Hash to be %myHash, you can copy the "Hash-Slice" with

```
%hashSlice = %{$myHash{a}};
```

Correcting your other typos above:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my %myHash = (
    'a' => {
        a1 => 'v1',
        a2 => 'v2'
    },
    'b' => {
        b1 => 'v3',
        b2 => 'v4'
    }
);

use Data::Dumper;

my %hashSlice = %{$myHash{a}};

print Dumper (\%hashSlice);
```

prints out

```
$VAR1 = {
      'a1' => 'v1',
      'a2' => 'v2'
    };
```

Comment: You got my vote. Perhaps it'd be nice to mention to possibility to make a reference to the inner hash to not have to copy all the data too? Something like `my $hashSliceRef = \%{$myHash{a}}; ${$hashSliceRef}{new_key_in_myHash} = 'new_data';` that will be visible through both `myHash` and `hashSliceRef`.

Comment: This would have been `my $hashSliceRef = $myHash{a};` Your code would create a reference to a copy.

Comment: BTW `$hashSliceRef->{new_key_in_myHash} = 'new_data';` Would then be the correct syntax.

Comment: `my $hashSliceRef = $myHash{a};` - Yes, that's even nicer (I've been off perl for a long time) :-). Adding some info about that may be useful. (not to argue, but isn't the ugly `${$hashSliceRef}{new_key_in_myHash}` also correct syntax?)

Comment: You are right - it is correct too - but not easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want a slice here; those retrieve multiple values at the same time. You are accessing a single element of hash to get at a single value, so the usual single-element access is what you want:

```
 my $value = $MyHash{'a'};
```

That value is happens to be another hash reference. I'd just leave it as a reference and get on with life. But, left as a reference, you have a *shallow copy*. Modifying the hash in `$value` modifies that value in `%MyHash`.

You can dereference it and assign it to a new hash. This is also a shallow copy, but only for the values now (if there was a second level of nesting):

```
 my %NewHash = %$value;
```

This is the same syntax you used, but the with the braces left off because I used a simple scalar:

```
 my %NewHash = %{ ...some hash ref... };
```

I like the [postfix dereferencing](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/) better:

```
 use v5.26;
 my %NewHash = $value->%*;
```

If you want a completely disconnected copy, [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable) can do that for you:

```
 use Storable qw(dclone);
 my $deep_copy = dclone($value);
```

### Slices

You use a hash slice to get multiple values. When they say "hash slice", this is what it means to most people (because this was the only sort of slice a hash has for a couple decades). The `@` is there to mean "multiple values":

```
 my @values = @MyHash{ @keys };
```

But, there's also a ["key-value" slice](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/07/perl-5-20-introduces-keyvalue-slices/) that returns keys and values (similar to how `each` does it):

```
 use v5.20;
 my %hash = %MyHash{ @keys };
```

You don't care about the key, `a`, you just want the value. This would still be one level too deep:

```
$VAR1 = {
      'a' => {
          'a1' => 'v1',
          'a2' => 'v2'
          }
    };
```